# How to insert encrypted data in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, encryption, oracle10g

I am inserting data in encrypted format so I have created a wallet in Oracle. But when I create table then give the error

> ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Transparent Data Encryption

So how to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comes if your database edition doesn't support the feature.

Transparent Data Encryption isn't available on Express & Standard editions, you'll need the [Enterprise edition and a separate license](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Transparent_Data_Encryption).

> According to the Oracle Database Licensing Information Guide: "Oracle Advanced Security provides transparent data encryption of data stored in the database". Advanced Security is a separately licensable option and can only be used with Oracle Enterprise Edition.